# App store using incorrect e-mail address as username - iPhone 6

Tags: mac-appstore, login, iphone

I upgraded my 4s to an iPhone 6 yesterday at the Sprint store. They transferred my data from the 4s to the 6, then erased the 4s. Now when trying to upgrade certain apps (such as Find My iPhone, Facebook, Linkedin Youtube, etc.) it prompts me for a password, but the associated username is an e-mail address I've never seen before and has no association to me or my Apple ID.

This is making it impossible to upgrade the apps and it's frustrating to see someone else's address associate. I've trying signing out of Apple, iCloud and the App store both online and via settings, resetting the iPhone each time — to no avail. Please help!

Comment: Any chance you used iCloud for backing up your previous phone?

Comment: How did you 'transfer' the data from old phone to new? There's actually no  method to do that directly.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to delete the apps and redownload them if you cannot login in the update prompt.

Comment: If they are just the apps mentioned in the OP's question, this is certainly the easiest approach.